# Batch command to FTP into linux server and move spooling files

Tags: command-line, batch-file, ssh, sftp

I am looking to create a batch file that will SFTP into a linux server and Move all the files in a directory to a network share.  However I am not sure how I would even start this.  Any help is appreciated.

Update: the box is using sftp not ftp, and I am going from window to linux.

Comment: From Mac ? Linux ? Windows ? =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to  do it using psftp.

```
 @ECHO OFF
 psftp USER@HOST.ADDRESS -pw PASSWORD -b psftp.bat
```

psftp.bat

```
cd /folder/test
lcd c:\test\
mv * /folder
cd /folder
mget *
rm *
bye
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute commands from the native **CMD**; When it switches over to anything like **FTP**, *you'll have to manually use commands like* **mget/get**. Maybe you can do it with **Visual Basic**, **C++** *C*, **Java**, *Or any other language?*

I would prefer these languages

*Lua*
*Java*
*C++*

Thanks!
*S2*